# Combining 4 tables using Union All and Group by ID and Description

Tags: sql-server

I want to combine 4 tables with non-homogeneous fields and group by `ID` and  `DESCRIPTION` and place all the uniform values in the same column as shown on the picture. I was able to query the union all but I can't move forward to grouping. How can I do this?

```
SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, RIGHT2, RIGHT3, RIGHT4, '1A' ENTITY
FROM tbla
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, '' RIGHT2, '' RIGHT3, '' RIGHT4, '1G' ENTITY
FROM tblb
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, '' RIGHT2, '' RIGHT3, '' RIGHT4, '1S' ENTITY
FROM tblc
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, '' RIGHT2, '' RIGHT3, '' RIGHT4, '1P' ENTITY
FROM tbld
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the data you are starting from rather than the result from your existing query. Also, please provide your data as tabular text rather than as images.

Comment: Hi @GMB this is actually related to the previous query you have made earlier, I’ve tried to include all the fields for each table but I was getting error “the fields are fewer than...” something like that. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64508233/combining-values-from-multiple-tables-using-join-clause-with-multiple-on/64508259?noredirect=1#comment114066382_64508259

Answer (score 0):

You can create a result set using these four tables and then apply the group by `ID` and `DESCRIPTION` as below:

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, RIGHT2, RIGHT3, RIGHT4, '1A' ENTITY
    FROM tbla
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, '' RIGHT2, '' RIGHT3, '' RIGHT4, '1G' ENTITY
    FROM tbla
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1ID, USERNAME, LOGIN_ID, DESCRIPTION, RIGHT1, '' RIGHT2, '' RIGHT3, '' RIGHT4, '1S' ENTITY
) Result 
GROUP BY Result.DESCRIPTION, Result.ID
```